# Extension on a Generic class

Tags: ios, swift, generics, associated-types

I have a class

```
class MyClass<T> { /***/ }
```

which I want to extend:

```
extension MyClass where T: Codable & RawRepresentable & CaseIterable { /***/ }
```

I want to constraint the extension to RawValues of type String so I'm trying to do something like:

```
extension MyClass where T: Codable & RawRepresentable & CaseIterable, RawValue == String { 
   func doSomething() {
      print("doing something with strings!")
   }
}
```

of course this doesn't work, but is there a way to make it work?

Would be helpful to be as explicit as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is just slightly wrong. `RawValue` belongs to `T`, so you need to reference it that way:

```
extension MyClass where T: Codable & RawRepresentable & CaseIterable,
                        T.RawValue == String { ... }
                        ^^
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple! Thanks!